# getIntentExtra devuelve default value

Tags: android

Hola a todos soy nuevo en android y estoy intentando pasar un entero de la actividad A a B y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, newClass.class);
 intent.putExtra("entero1", 5);
 startActivity(intent);`

Y en la actividad B intento recibir el valor 5 de esta forma:

`Intent intent = getIntent();
 int activityValue = intent.getIntExtra("entero1", 0);`

Al hacer esto siempre me regresa el valor por default, en este caso el 0 y lo que quiero es recibir el 5 que se puso en el `putExtra`.
Alguien me podría explicar por qué sucede esto?

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

He encontrado cómo hacer que el getIntExtra devuelva el valor deseado.
A continuación les muestro mi ejemplo:
Primero en la clase de la actividad "A" declaro una variable global

```
public static final String rack_number = "com.engeimanga.smartrack.racknumber";
```

(El valor de esta string está dado por: (su dominio).(el nombre de su app).(el nombre que quieran)

Cuando creo el intent y hago el putExtra mando el nombre de la variable global y el valor que quiero enviar a la actividad "B"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newClass.class);
intent.putExtra(rack_number, 5);
startActivity(intent);
```

Dentro de la actividad "B" para recibir el valor de manera correcta hago lo siguiente:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int number;
number = intent.getIntExtra(LoginScreen.rack_number, 0);
```

Al hacer esto en la variable number ya está guardado el valor que se envió desde la actividad "A"  El primer argumento de getIntExtra es: (el nombre de la actividad desde donde envían el extra).(el nombre de la variable global que creamos).
Todo esto lo hice basándome en un ejemplo de la página de android developers.

Para ser sincero no entiendo muy bien por qué funciona de esta forma y no como lo tenía anteriormente si alguien me lo pudiera explicar se lo agradecería. Mientras tanto aquí hay una forma para hacerlo.
Saludos

Comment: A primera vista lo estas haciendo bien, no hay nada raro en ese código. ¿No estará el error por otro lado? ¿Estas mostrando activityValue? ¿Has probado a definir antes un `int envio = 5;` y enviarlo en `intent.putExtra("entero1", envio);`?

Comment: @Wyrncael Si estoy mostrando el activityValue. Acabo de hacer la prueba definiendo antes `int envio = 5` y sigue teniendo el mismo comportamiento. Regresa el default value.

Comment: Yo uso un operador ternario (en la actividad B), para recibir el valor, en caso de que éste sea pasado. Algo así: `int activityValue = (this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) ? getIntent().getIntExtra("entero1") : 0;`. Eso sí, tienes que hacerlo en el `onCreate` de la actividad B.

Comment: Como lo estabas haciendo al principio no te funcionaba porque estabas usando de nuevo `Intent` en la actividad B, en realidad, para obtener el valor bastaría con que hagas esto en el  `onCreate`: `int activityValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("entero1");` No obstante, es bueno siempre verificar que el `Intent` se ha enviado, como te mostré en el comentario anterior. No hace falta liarse creando variables globales y cosas de ese tipo. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por la ayuda! Lo probé con el operador ternario como mencionaste y funcionó. Posteriormente lo volví a intentar como lo tenía en un principio y ahora funciona correctamente. De cualquier forma gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre es bueno verificar la **no nulidad** de los datos pasados en un `Intent` por diversos motivos:

- porque se puede estar pasando un valor nulo por cualquier motivo que escapa a nuestro control
- porque podemos tener `Activitys` que en algunos escenarios necesiten datos extra, pero en otros no
- etc

Para manejar cualquiera de estas situaciones posibles, puedes usar un operador ternario que verifique si no se está pasando un valor nulo en el `Intent`. De ese modo, el operador ternario asignará a la variable sea el valor pasado en el `Intent`, sea un valor por defecto (`0` en este caso).

#### Activity que envía el `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newClass.class);
intent.putExtra(rack_number, 5);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Activity que recibe el `Intent`

En el `onCreate` de la `Activity` que va a recibir los datos, puedes poner esto:

```
int activityValue = (this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) ? getIntent().getIntExtra("entero1") : 0;.
```

El valor de `activityValue` tendrá: o el número que se pase en el `Intent` o `0` en caso de que ningún valor se haya pasado. De ese modo se evitará tener un *`Null Pointer Exception`** en caso de que la Activity que recibe el `Intent` sea llamada desde algún sitio desde el cual no se envíen datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar primeramente si en verdad se recibe un `bundle` con información:

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      //Contiene información.
    }
```

Si el `bundle` contiene información, entonces verificar que los valores que deseas obtener en realidad existen:

```
   int number;
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      //Contiene información.

        if (extras.containsKey("entero1")) {
            number = extras.getInt("entero1");
        }

    }
```